# Upgrade SonarQube issues

Tags: service, jenkins, webserver, sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0

I'm having issues installing my instance of `SonarQube` 4.4 to 5.1.

The [instructions](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading) say to stop the SonarQube server, match up a couple files (back up DB, copy plugins, etc.), and then restart the sonar server for the updated version.

My problem is I'm not sure how to start/stop the server. The commands:

```
bin/<SYSTEM>/sonar stop
```

and

```
NEW_SONARQUBE_HOME/bin/<SYSTEM>/sonar start
```

aren't recognized. Here is what the file location looks like and this is the error I get when I `StartSonar` on the new instance.

[image]
When I start from the 5.1
[image]
When I start from the 4.4
[image]

Error in sonar log. I'm using port 9000 so I'm not sure why it's trying to get 9001

```
    2015.06.12 09:59:47 ERROR web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:730) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:457) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:120) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:960) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:567) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:851) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:340) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.start(EmbeddedTomcat.java:62) [sonar-server-5.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.start(WebServer.java:40) [sonar-server-5.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:77) [sonar-process-5.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.main(WebServer.java:66) [sonar-server-5.1.1.jar:na]
2015.06.12 09:59:47 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.StandardService] Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-9000]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-9000]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:567) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:851) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:340) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.start(EmbeddedTomcat.java:62) [sonar-server-5.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.start(WebServer.java:40) [sonar-server-5.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:77) [sonar-process-5.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.main(WebServer.java:66) [sonar-server-5.1.1.jar:na]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:962) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:730) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:457) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:120) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:960) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    ... 11 common frames omitted
2015.06.12 09:59:47 WARN  web[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Fail to start web
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardServer[-1]]
    at com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:156) ~[guava-10.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.start(EmbeddedTomcat.java:65) ~[sonar-server-5.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.start(WebServer.java:40) [sonar-server-5.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:77) ~[sonar-process-5.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.main(WebServer.java:66) [sonar-server-5.1.1.jar:na]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardServer[-1]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.start(EmbeddedTomcat.java:62) ~[sonar-server-5.1.1.jar:na]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:851) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-9000]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:574) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
2015.06.12 09:59:47 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.TerminatorThread] Process[search] is stopping
2015.06.12 09:59:47 INFO   es[o.s.p.StopWatcher]  Stopping process
2015.06.12 09:59:47 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1434117578819] stopping ...
2015.06.12 09:59:47 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1434117578819] stopped
2015.06.12 09:59:47 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1434117578819] closing ...
2015.06.12 09:59:47 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1434117578819] closed
2015.06.12 09:59:47 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.TerminatorThread] Process[search] is stopped
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

How do I stop/start the SonarQube web server and proceed with the upgrade?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On Windows, the scripts are indeed different:

- if you haven't installed SonarQube as a service, you should read ["Running SonarQube as a Service on Windows"](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Running+SonarQube+as+a+Service+on+Windows) to know how to start and stop
- if not, then:

  - to start SonarQube, you have to execute the "StartSonar.bat" script: this will open a Command window
  - to stop SonarQube, just close the window that was opened

The difference between SQ 4.4 and SQ 5.1 is that in most recent versions, when you start SonarQube, it creates 3 different processes:

- 1 for the Web server (port 9000)
- 1 for Elasticsearch (port 9001)
- and 1 to monitor the previous 2 ones

So what happens in your log (`Address already in use: bind`) is clear: you have a running process of Elasticsearch. So to fix your problem:

- Open Windows task manager
- Kill all the Java processes
- Restart SQ

Comment: I've edited the question to show the error I get when I conduct that step.

Comment: There's no problem in what you added. It's just the regular logs showing that your SQ server has started :-)

Comment: I'm just confused because I followed all the steps and get different messages when I run StartSonar for 4.4 and 5.1. And when I visit the Sonar page it still says 4.4 at the bottom

Comment: If you stil see 4.4, this means that you have missed some steps during the upgrade process.

Comment: I was expecting something more along the lines of the third picture, which starts the server and allows me to access Sonar.

Comment: You are asking too many different things in a single question, this is getting a mess. I'm going to update my answer, and then please ask another question.

Comment: You are a life saver

Comment: Hi Fabrice I am getting address binding error when I am trying to run Sonar,can you help me with solution @Fabrice-SonarSourceTeam

Answer (score 2):

The new sonar needs two ports, 9000 for the web server and 9001 for search something. However, in most of the tutorials 9001 is not mentioned.

There is a clash for Universal Media Server which by default starts a web server at port 9001.

You should change one of the ports, however the port used for sonar search should not be public!